# perform joins in pyspark on multiple keys with only duplicating non identical column names

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to outer join two dataframes with Spark:

```
df1 columns: first_name, last, address 
df2 columns: first_name, last_name, phone_number
```

My keys are `first_name and df1.last==df2.last_name`

I want the final dataset schema to contain the following columnns:

`first_name, last, last_name, address, phone_number`

Which means if column names are identical, I want to 'merge' the columns in the output dataframe, and if there are not identical, I want to keep both columns separate.

I am not able to do this in one join but only two joins like:
`df1.join(df2,'first_name','outer').join(df2,[df1.last==df2.last_name],'outer')`

Comment: I suggest you create an example of your input data and expected output -- this will make it much easier for people to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the join in a single step by using a join condition with multiple elements:

```
join_cond = [df1.first_name == df2.first_name, df1.last == df2.last_name]
df_join = df1.join(df2, join_cond, 'outer')
```

Comment: Thanks @abeboparebop but this expression duplicates columns even the ones with identical column names (e.g. will create two first_name columns in the output dataset and in the case of outer joins, these will have different content). Looking for a solution that will return one column for first_name (a la SQL), and separate columns for last and last_name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
join_cond = [df1.first_name == df2.first_name, df1.last == df2.last_name]
df_join = df1.alias('l').join(df2.alias('r'), join_cond, 'outer').select(fn.col('l.first_name').alias('first_name'), fn.col('l.last').alias('last'), fn.col('r.last_name').alias('last_name'))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).